# Изменить подстроку в строке с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка `[mod]тут может быть что угодно[/mod]`, она находится в неком тексте ( строке ), нужно средствами php заменить выше приведенную строку на некую другую, Спасибо!

Comment: С чем именно у вас возникли проблемы: составлением регулярного выражения или неведением существования метода [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)? Допустим, есть у нас строка ```$string = 'Некий текст, [mod]какой-то текст[/mod]. Еще текст.';```, меняем в ней `какой-то текст` на `заменено`: ```echo preg_replace('#(?<=\]).+(?=\[)#', 'изменено', $string);```

Comment: да нету сейчас времени вкуривать регулярки

Comment: @russell, примите ответ, если он решил вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$tagStart = '\[mod\]';
$tagEnd = '\[\/mod\]';
// Начинаем захват с открывающего тега, 
// нежадно матчим до первого закрывающего
$regexp = '@'.$tagStart.'.+?'.$tagEnd.'@m';

$textWas = '[mod]Тут у нас что угодно[/mod]';

echo preg_replace($regexp, 'Текст На Замену', $textWas);
```

Comment: спасибо, но [mod] и [/mod] тоже нужно удалить

Comment: @russell Тогда всё ещё проще — исправил код, вырезает тег с содержимым полностью.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующее выражение:

```
'/\[mod][^\[]+\[\/mod]/'
```

- `\[mod]` - открывающий тег `[mod]`
- `[^\[]+` - захват до первой встречной квадратной скобки `[`
- `\[\/mod]` - закрывающий тег `[/mod]`

[См. демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/5yNmh1/3)

Пример:

```
$text = 'Контенту [mod]тут может быть что угодно[/mod] нужно внимание';
echo preg_replace('/\[mod][^\[]+\[\/mod]/', '|замена|', $text);
```